# Running command line Maple script interactively

Tags: maple

I'm connecting over ssh to a machine running Maple. Is there a way to run a script, let's say derp.mpl, such that after executing the script Maple is still running?

Something perhaps analogous to running python like this:

```
python -i derp.py
```

Comment: I realize that this is actually a bad question (about Maple rather than math) however It still seems to be the most appropriate stack exchange site for this. Sorry in advance!

Comment: http://www.mapleprimes.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -F option allows the session to stay open (not quit) after completing whatever computation was started by the script.

```
maple -F derp.mpl
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to run a script from the Maple command line ?

Is it possible to access to the terminal of the unix system in Maple itself ?
(like in Mathematica, we can access it by ! my command)

Comment: In the command-line/terminal Maple interface (in Linux/Unix) you can use `!` in front of a command you want sent to the parent shell. You can also use the Maple commands `system` and `ssystem` in either the command-line or graphical-user (GUI) interfaces. See the Maple help-pages for those two commands.